# Play Video on Scollify change

Tags: html, video, scroll, html5-video, jquery-scrollify

I have a page with 3 [Scrollify](https://projects.lukehaas.me/scrollify/) sliders. The 2nd slider contains a paused video. I'm trying to figure out a way so that when you scroll to the 2nd slider it plays the video, and it pauses if you scroll away.

I've tried:

```
$(".video").focus(function(){
  $("video").play();
});

$(".video").focusout(function(){
  $("video").pause();
});
```

and:

```
$(".slider").on("beforeChange", function (){
  $("video").play();
});
```

Here's a [codepen](http://codepen.io/katiemoons/pen/ac696b89b5616718dbd99b8cad8ee755?editors=0010) demo.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Use Scrollify's `before` or `after` callbacks to achieve this.

Comment: Thank you for answering me directly, I wasn't expecting to hear from the author :) , I managed to get it to work by using:

before: function(nextIndex, elements) {
  $(".video").get(0).play();
},

Is it possible to only run this when moving to the 2nd slide?

Comment: @luke-hass perhaps using:

before: function(nextIndex, elements)

Comment: Yes, use the nextIndex to work out which slide it's moving to.

Comment: @luke-hass how to I determine the index of the section?

Comment: The slides are indexed in the order they appear on the page, starting at zero

Comment: @luke-hass I tried this:

data-section-name="s1"

before: function(s2) {
 $("#video").get(0).play();
},

Comment: @luke-hass http://codepen.io/katiemoons/pen/ac696b89b5616718dbd99b8cad8ee755?editors=0010

Comment: @luke-hass and this  
before: function(1) {
   $("#video").get(0).play();
},

Comment: If you console log your s2 variable you'll see the index of each slide as you scroll to it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137489/discussion-between-kathrynm-and-luke-haas).